# How to make a button appear if a progress bar is at a value of 100?

Tags: javascript, function

I am making a simple quiz game, and I'm trying to show a result bar when the player has finished the quiz. Each time they answer a question a `<progress>` tag is increased by a `.value` of 10 until it reaches 100, that is when I want the result button to appear. Here is my current code, I cannot figure out what is wrong. (`progBar` is a global variable for the progress bar.) I've tried to use `==` with no success and I also tried turning `result` into a global variable but still nothing.

```
function showResult() {
    if(progBar.value === 100) {
        let result = document.getElementById("results");
        result.style.display="block";
    };
};
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: please add working snippet

Answer (score 0):

Should be `progBar.value == 100` Because the returned value from `input` is not integer value. Or you can use `progBar.value === "100"`

Comment: That's really all there is I just need to figure out how to make that function work

Comment: Are you sure you called the function?